# What do I need disk space on a Xbox 360 for?

Tags: xbox-360

I've never had an Xbox 360 but I want to get one. I don't want to do any hardcore gaming like Halo, only lighter stuff like the Skate games and Family Guy, Back to the Multiverse. So, in order to decide if the 4GB edition is good enough for me, I'd like to know what does the XBox *need* the hard drive for? Do games require to be installed on disk perhaps? What about demos or XBLA?

Comment: Hi @user52528, welcome to the site! If the answers below helped you, you can mark one of them as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark below the vote count :)

Answer (score 4):

4 GB should be plenty. Game saves usually don't take up much space at all. Large amounts of hard drive space is more for if you want to download retail games and stuff like that. Plus, you can always plug in a flash drive/external storage if you find you end up playing more than just those games.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons you might want more space, including

- The ability to install games on your Xbox. This speeds up transfer rates while playing but is nothing more than a mild luxury in time.
- The ability to buy, download, and play games and demos from the Xbox Live Arcade/Digital Store, including massive retail titles like Skyrim. These take up considerable space, but given your current playing/buying preferences, you should be fine with just regular discs.
- Storing/Playing lots of media from your Xbox. Movies, pictures, music and more can all be played back from the Xbox, and take up space.

Given your listed gaming preferences, you should be fine with just a [regular 4GB Xbox for $200](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/html/pbPage.PDP/productID.282125500), as you don't appear to need any extra storage space. Worst-case cheapo scenario, buy a flash drive and plug it for some extra storage, or go all out with a USB hard drive.